# Find 2 or more consecutive Capital letter in a string

Tags: regex, search, regex-lookarounds, case-sensitive

While working with java code linting and formatting I was getting error to remove all consecutive capital letters in variables, classs, function name. So to find all those words in source code this regex worked.

```
Example:-

 - testSTring  ---> match
 - testString  ---> no match
 - TEstString  ---> match
 - teststrING  ---> match
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex :-

```
([A-Z]{2,})
```